# Juros compostos em Python utilizando "while"

Tags: python, python-3.x, matemática, while, condição

Recentemente estava tentando resolver um exercício para aprender Python, mas encontrei grandes problemas quando tentei calcular os juros compostos. Utilizei a **fórmula matemática do montante** e simplesmente **não faço a menor ideia do que este errado** (em especial com a **27° linha**. Acredito que o problema de lógica está lá, seja lá qual for)**.**

**Abaixo está o meu código defeituoso:**

```
c = float(input('Digite o depósito inicial: R$'))
i = float(input('Agora, digite a taxa de juros de uma poupança: '))
t = 1   # Contador dos meses
c2 = None
while t <= 24:
    m = c * (1 + (i / 100)) ** t
    if t == 1:
        print(f'\nNo mês {t}, o valor dos juros será igual a R${m:.2f}')
    else:
        print(f'\nNo mês {t}, o valor dos juros será igual a R${m:.2f}')

    if t == 24:
        break

    t = t + 1

    op = input(f'Deseja realizar um depósito para o {t}° mês[S/N]? ').strip().upper()[0]

    while op != 'S' and op != 'N':
        op = input(f'OPÇÃO INVÁLIDA! Deseja realizar um depósito para o {t}° mês[S/N]? ').strip().upper()[0]

    if op == 'S':
        c2 = float(input(f'Digite o valor do depósito do {t}° mês: R$'))

    else:
        c2 = 0
    c = c2 + m

j = c * (1 + (i / 100)) ** t
print(f'No total, a quantidade de reais ganha com os JUROS COMPOSTOS será igual a R${j - c:.2f}')
```

Busquei algumas **referências** para a **resolução desse problema**, em especial o post no blog do Professor Nilo, autor do livro "**Introdução à Programação com Pyhton - Algoritmos e lógica de programação para iniciantes**", onde se encontra esse exercício (Sendo mais específico, é o **exercício 5.12 do 5° capítulo**)

- https://python.nilo.pro.br/exercicios/capitulo%2005/exercicio-05-12.html

**DETALHE IMPORTANTE:** Notei que, no link acima, o **professor NÃO utiliza a fórmula convencional matemática do Montante**, mas simplesmente não entendi o porquê

Para auto-correção, utilizei diversos sites, mas o principal simulador de juros compostos foi este:

- https://mepoupe.com/simuladores-online-de-investimentos/simulador-de-juros-composto/

Comment: Não pude deixar de notar que a "pontuação" da minha pergunta caiu. Por favor, deixe sugestões abaixo, para que eu possa esclarecer os trechos que ficaram confusos e melhorar o entendimento da minha pergunta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vamos esquecer por um tempo as linhas de código e focar na lógica do programa. Deixando as fórmulas de lado, vamos entender o problema. Uma aplicação de juros compostos mensais nada mais é do que um capital que se "atualiza" ao final de cada mês. Para fazer essa "atualização", segue-se um parâmetro que no caso é somar ao valor do mês anterior um valor extra(juros). Esse valor extra é definido pela taxa de juros multiplicado pelo valor do mês anterior (no caso do juro simples, a multiplicação seria sempre pelo capital inicial). Tendo isso em mente, podemos esquecer a fórmula e pensar:

capital inicial = x  |  taxa de juros = 1% a.m.

```
primeiro mês = capital inicial + (capital inicial * 0.01)
```

`segundo mês = primeiro mês + (primeiro mês * 0.01)`  + aporte (caso exista)

`terceiro mês = segundo mês + (segundo mês * 0.01)`   + aporte (caso exista)

...

Assim, constrói-se o programa sem a fórmula:

```
capital_inicial = float(input('Digite o depósito inicial: R$'))
i = float(input('Agora, digite a taxa de juros de uma poupança: '))
i = (i/100) # Definindo o valor de i separadamente para deixar o código mais limpo
t = 1   # Contador dos meses
aporte = 0 # Não coloque c2. É muito confuso.

while t < 24:
    if t == 1:
        m = capital_inicial + (capital_inicial * i) # Ou: m = capital_inicial * (1 + i)
        print(f'\nNo mês {t}, o valor dos juros será igual a R${m:.2f}')
    else:
        print(f'\nNo mês {t}, o valor dos juros será igual a R${m:.2f}')

    t = t + 1 # Mesma coisa escrever: t += 1

    op = input(f'Deseja realizar um depósito para o {t}° mês[S/N]? ').strip().upper()[0]
    while op != 'S' and op != 'N':
        op = input(f'OPÇÃO INVÁLIDA! Deseja realizar um depósito para o {t}° mês[S/N]? ').strip().upper()[0]

    if op == 'S':
        aporte = float(input(f'Digite o valor do depósito do {t}° mês: R$'))
    else:
        aporte = 0

    m = m + (m * i) + aporte # Ou: m = m * (1 + i) + aporte

ganho_com_juros = m - capital_inicial # (montante final - capital inicial)
print(f'No total, a quantidade de reais ganha com os JUROS COMPOSTOS será igual a R${ganho_com_juros}')
```

Algumas dicas:

-> Sempre que estiver com dúvidas desse tipo, esqueça o código e foque primeiro na lógica.

-> De nomes autoexplicativos a suas variáveis. Não poupe na hora de definir o nome! Isso vai fazer você identificar o bug mais rápido.

Comment: Sua resposta ficou clara, compreendi o raciocínio. Apesar disso, fiz alguns testes, em especial no simulador de juros compostos citado na dúvida, e notei que o montante final difere da variável "m" no programa com seu valor final, ainda que a variação seja pequena. Fiz mais alguns testes e notei que era porque os simuladores na internet consideram o aporte logo no primeiro mês, e levando isso em consideração no programa, a diferença ficou ainda menor, mas ainda existia. O senhor saberia me responder o por quê disso acontecer?